# PHP - get always the same random numbers by key

Tags: php, random

maybe I am trying something impossible, that's why I am asking :-)

I want to get 10 random numbers in specific range. But I want to specify key or hash by which would be these random numbers generated. So when ever I specify the same key, I will always get the same random numbers.

Is it possible, if yes, how ? Thanks for any help or hints.

Explanation: If is someone interested why I want to do this - it's for recipes site, where I want all day display exact same randomly picked recipes (day number = key) so they change every day, but stay the same all day long.

Comment: Are you just looking for the http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php function?

Comment: It is the wrong approach to generated query a random generator each time. Do it once, save the result for the say and use that result throughout the day.

Comment: Make the rand's seed dependent on the current day. Calling rand will then generate the same sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personnaly go for a stored version of what you are suggesting.

Every day, the first request made to the website will pick n random recipes and store them in the database, in a "recipe_by_days" table, containing the day (2013-09-16) and the list of picked recipes.

Then the next visitors will get the list just by querying that table with the day being today.

That made, it would be possible to list the randomly picked recipes that was out y days before.

But then, this implementation is useful if you want to keep the randomly picked recipes more than for today only.

Now if you are interested in just showing the same randomly picked recipes for the current day only, and not keep an history, you can then just add a column to your recipe table that can be null.

Every day, the first request will set this column to null, pick n random recipes, and update the column of theses to the current date.

The algo is quite simple :

```
Select the recipes that have "today_random" set to "today".
If none is returned (because they are in "yesterday" state) :
     Set the column "today_random" from all the recipes to null
     Pick n random recipes, update the "today_random" column of these to "today"
     Return these selected recipes
else return the result
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this post has the function you want:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php#90215

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array of days, let's assume for week days, and just get the current day's recipies:

```
$recipies = array(
  0 => array(...), // sunday
  1 => array(...), // monday
  2 => array(...), // tuesday
  ...
);

print_r($recipies[date("w")]); // current weekday's recipies
```

Then you can randomise for that particular array with `array_shuffle` or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

This will consistently pick 10 random numbers between `$lowerRange` and `$upperRange`, based on a key:

```
mt_srand(crc32('your-key'));
$lowerRange = 100;
$upperRange = 200;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $choices[] = mt_rand($lowerRange, $upperRange);
}

print_r($choices);
```